# Pyparsing: grouping results by keywords ending with colons

Tags: pyparsing

I am new to `pyparsing`. Although did try to read through the docs, I did not manage to solve the first problem of grouping expressions by "keyword: token(s)". I ended up with this code:

```py
import pyparsing
from pprint import pprint

token = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
keyword = pp.Combine(token + pp.Literal(":"))
expr = pp.Group(keyword[1] + token[1, ...])

pprint(expr.parse_string("keyA: aaa bb ccc keyB: ddd eee keyC: xxx yyy hhh zzz").as_list())
```

It stops in the middle and parses the second `keyword` as a regular token. The result is following:

the expression:

```
keyA: aaa bb ccc keyB: ddd eee keyC: xxx yyy hhh zzz
```

gets parsed into:

```
[['keyA:', 'aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'keyB']]
```

I cannot figure out how to define `keyword` and `token`.

---

Edit.

In general, I'd like to parse the following expression:

```
keyword1: token11 token12 ... keyword2: token21 & token22 token23 keyword3: (token31 token32) & token33
```

into the following list:

```py
[
    ["keyword1:", "token11", "token12", ...],
    ["keyword2:", ["token21", "&", "token22"], "token23"],
    ["keyword3:", [["token31", "token32"], "&", "token33"]],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I was looking for a way to specify that `token` ends with an alphanumeric character, that is not `:`. It turns out Pyparsing has a function `WordEnd()`, which I used, with which the expression is correctly parsed.

```py
import pyparsing
from pprint import pprint

token = pp.Combine(pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.WordEnd())
keyword = pp.Combine(pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.Literal(":"))
expr = pp.Group(keyword[1] + token[1, ...])[1, ...]

pprint(expr.parse_string("keyA: aaa bb ccc keyB: ddd eee keyC: xxx yyy hhh zzz").as_list())
```

```py
[['keyA:', 'aaa', 'bb', 'ccc'],
 ['keyB:', 'ddd', 'eee'],
 ['keyC:', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'hhh', 'zzz']]
```

Comment: Glad to see you solved this. In place of `WordEnd()` you could also try a negative lookahead using the '~' (`NotAny`) operator and `FollowedBy`, as in `token = Word(alphas) + ~FollowedBy(":")`.

Answer (score 1):

To add support for the '&' operator as in your original post, you were very close with your use of `infixNotation`. In your original, you had an expression like "a b & c", which you wanted to parse as `['a', ['b', '&', 'c']`. The first issue you had was with the token vs. key issue, which you have resolved for yourself. The second issue has to do with your operators. It is possible in `infixNotation` to define an empty operator using a Python None for the operator expression. Since you have defined your expression to make this of lower precedence than '&', then you would define your expression as:

```
expr = infixNotation(token,
    [
        ('&', 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
        (None, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
    ])
```

Use runTests to quickly run a bunch of tests:

```
expr.runTests("""\
    a b c
    a & b
    a & b & c
    a & b c
    a & (b c)
""", fullDump=False)
```

Prints:

```
a b c
[['a', 'b', 'c']]

a & b
[['a', '&', 'b']]

a & b & c
[['a', '&', 'b', '&', 'c']]

a & b c
[[['a', '&', 'b'], 'c']]

a & (b c)
[['a', '&', ['b', 'c']]]
```

Comment: Thanks. My parse has been quite expanded since I asked the question. I took your advice into account and added new lines to the code. So far, it seems to be parsing everything correctly. The only missing bit is how to add `nested_expr()`. I can't figure it out. I am quite new to pyparsing :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to add `nested_expr()` to handle parentheses (see the last test case above). `infix_notation` includes support for grouping with ()'s.